# subfigures misalignment

Tags: captions, subfloats, alignment

I'm trying to plot 6 subfigures over two rows. Here's my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
     \centering
     \foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
     {
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
         \caption{Test$\x$}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     }
     \caption{Title}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It works as expected, however the subfigures are not aligned
[image]

So figure `(2,1)` seems fine but then the others on the second row are too much on the left. How can I solve this? I also tried replacing `[t]` with `[b]` or `[h]` but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code executes `\hfill` after every image, including the final one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to remove the last `\hfill`, which is easy: add `%` after the closing brace (or `\par`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tp]

\foreach \x in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} {
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    %{lDSX distr \x} {1, 5, 10, 15, 25, 50}
  \caption{Test$\x$}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
}% <---- or \par

\caption{Title}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Why does this happen? Without the `%` the endline generates a space and the following blank line (or `\caption`) generates a `\par` that just removes *one* glob of glue. If the space is not generated to begin with, the last glob of glue is `\hfill`, which is so removed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Right now, your code executes `\hfill` after each and every `subfigure` environment. Ideally, though, your code would execute `\hfill` only after `subfigure` environments 1, 2, 4, and 5 -- and execute `\par` after numbers 3 and 6.

This may be achieved by changing

```
\hfill
```

to

```
\ifnum\x=3\par\else\ifnum\x=6\par\else\hfill\fi\fi
```

Of course, if you wanted to insert a bit of whitespace between the two rows of  subfigures, you might write

```
\ifnum\x=3\par\bigskip\else\ifnum\x=6\par\else\hfill\fi\fi
```

---

The full example would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
     %\centering % not needed
     \foreach \x in {1,...,6}
     {
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
         \caption{Test$\x$}
     \end{subfigure}
     \ifnum\x=3\par\else\ifnum\x=6\par\else\hfill\fi\fi
     }
     \caption{Title}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]